# How to get iFrame source code inside a webview?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I want to get iFrame source code inside a webview, but I am getting an error :-

```
"Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://........." from accessing a frame with origin "https://.........".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
```

Please throw some insight into the error.

NB:- I cannot change the address from http to https.

Answer (score 0):

With that error logs, I think the protocol of main URL is http:// and you want add iFrame with url protocol https:// that It throw that exception, You can try use same protocol http:// for this case.